# Pause setInterval function and run it again

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

I have a slider script which use `setInterval` to run next slider function for a period of time, this function also called by another event listener, the problem is the function can run at nearest period, so the transition is bad. I want to make `setInterval` pause for awhile when I  run the function from event listener.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     setInterval(function () { 
        next(); 
     }, 5000);

     function prev() {
       //slide in to left                
     };

     function next() {
       //slide in to right                  
     };

     $('#prev').click(function (e) {
       pause = 1;
       prev();
       setTimeout(function(){
        pause = 0;
       }, 3000);
     });

     $('#next').click(function (e) {
      pause = 1; 
      next();
      setTimeout(function(){
         pause = 0;
      }, 3000);
     });
 });
```